# AWS SageMaker - Request has Invalid image format

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm testing Amazon SageMaker service with NodeJS + AWS SDK and after create a new model and endpoint based on [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-fulltraining.ipynb) example (everything works well in the notebook, including the request to the endpoint), I'm trying to create requests from my Express application, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error during recognition: { InvalidImageFormatException: Request has Invalid image format
  at Request.extractError (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
  at Request.callListeners (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:109:20)
  at Request.emit (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:81:10)
  at Request.emit (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
  at Request.transition (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
  at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
  at /Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
  at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
  at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
  at Request.callListeners (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:119:18)
  at Request.emit (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:81:10)
  at Request.emit (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
  at Request.transition (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
  at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
  at /Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
  at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pdonaire/Documents/workspaceNode/trsps-controller/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)

message: 'Request has Invalid image format',
code: 'InvalidImageFormatException',
time: 2018-09-10T04:42:07.530Z,
requestId: 'de3a04ff-b4b3-11e8-9bd8-8b88f803570c',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 55.860720412209794 }
```

My code is as follows:

```
export function sendRequestToSageMaker(base64image) {
  const params = {
    Body: new Buffer(base64image, 'base64') , /* Strings will be Base-64 encoded on your behalf */ /* required */
    EndpointName: 'DEMO-imageclassification-ep--XXXX', /* required */
    Accept: 'application/json',
    ContentType: 'application/x-image'
  };
  sagemakerruntime.invokeEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) 
      console.error(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     
      console.log(data);           // successful response
   });
   return null;
}
```

`base64image` is `req.body.photo` from a request that I'm doing with Postman with a JSON and just a single `photo` property with a base64 string that I've made with [base64-image.de](https://www.base64-image.de/) website.

Any help will be helpful! Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Maybe you could try sending the image as form-data multipart instead of bas64

Answer (score 0):

the SageMaker image classification algorithm only supports images as payload and does not support base64 encoded payload and that is why you see the InvalidImageFormatException.